# JQuery .find() function for multiple array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code snippet

```
for (var k = 0; k < link_list.length; k++) {
    var service_list = document.getElementsByName("service_info");
    service_list = $(service_list).children("div[name=service_info_element]");
    for (var i = 0; i < service_list.length; i++){
        var service_info = {};
        service_info["service_name"] = $(service_list[i]).find("select[name=service_name]").val();
        service_info["service_type"] = $(service_list[i]).find("input[name=service_type]").val();

    }
```

How can I get `$(service_list[i]).find("select[name=service_name]").val()` and `$(service_list[i]).find("input[name=service_type]").val();` for each `link_list[k]` inside the second loop. I mean I need something like `link_list[k].service_list[i].find("select[name=service_name]").val()`

Comment: How about `$.each` with `$(this)` ?

Comment: have you tried .each()??

Comment: I faced some problems with .each() to get my desired result. Anyway I have solved it using the following line: 
var service_list = $(link_list[k]).find("div[name=service_info_element]");
thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it'll work
    $('service_list[i]').find('select[name=service_name]').filter([0,3,4]).anything();

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
link_list[k].service_list[i].find("select[name=service_name]").each(function(i, element){
    var val = $(this).val(); // or element.val()
});
```